# Multiple require() calls VS a just one with a larger file?

Tags: php, wordpress, require

*(This question is about PHP's require function, so bear with me on the set up)*

I have a Wordpress theme with extensive customizations, all running through add_action or add_filter. The usual recommendation for where to place this code is your theme's functions.php files. I don't support this because it becomes a mess of unrelated code. In order to create a more organized theme, I instead organize them in directories and files based on the subject matter and it they should be trigger on the frontend or dashboard.

This means however that my functions.php file has many (many many) require('...php') calls.  I've seen posts online which specifically towards the disadvantages of require_one, so I've already eliminated that.

**Do you think I would have worthwhile savings in page rendering if I were to look into a way of cutting this down to 2 or 3 required files which contain the contents of all the multiple files combined.**

I thought about using Grunt to contat the files (similar to how it's often done with JS files).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you considered autoloading?

Comment: I couldn't tell. Firstly, we know little about your files, and secondly we have no idea when you would think it is a worthwhile saving. My guess would be that there will not be a big change in speed, but the only way to know for sure is to actually test this.

Comment: @smith Autoloading is a nice idea, but this is just a collection of Wordpress/WooCommerce related code. It's not structured as classes.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks. I can test, but figured there would be someone with more in-depth understanding and expertise on here that could offer some insight.